# Joining specific 2 rows of existing list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question I have a list let us say:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { A, B, C, D, E, F, G}
```

And I need to combine specific two rows of that list to new new list for example:

```
List<string> rebuildList = new List<string> { A, B, CD, E, FG}
```

I already made a code that would work:

```
var joinDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 3, 4 }, { 7, 8 } };
foreach (var value in list)
{
    var index = list.IndexOf(value);
    if (joinDictionary.ContainsKey(index))
    {
        rebuildList.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", value, list.ElementAt(index + 1)));
    }

    if (!joinDictionary.ContainsKey(index) && !joinDictionary.ContainsValue(index))
    {
        rebuildList.Add(value);
    }
}
```

But is there more elegant way to do this? Sole linq lambda query maybe?

Comment: You always want to join the 3rd with the 4th and the 7th with the 8th? Everytime there are exactly 2 joins?

Comment: @ThomasD. the `joinDictionary` dictates what to join.

Comment: I'm not sure if it gets any more readable with LINQ. I will give it a try tho.

Comment: Instead of `foreach`ing over the values and then do `IndexOf(value)`, you'd better loop over the index and do`value = list[index]`. Also `list[index+1]` instead of `list.ElementAt(index+1)`

Comment: @Dennis_E be aware that this requires that you always join two neighbors, which is not explicitly stated in the question. The described approach is more generic.

Comment: @ThomasD. I suppose. In that case, ignore the 1st part of that comment

Comment: Are there any restrictions we can assume on the `joinDictionary` or have to follow in the expected result? Like we only join neighbors, we only join with higher numbers, every number may appear in the dictionary only once, we have to preserve the order of the list (if so, what to do if the `joinDictionary` contains a pair of non-neighbors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your dictionary to be zero based, you can use something like:

```
list.
    Select((str, ind) => joinDictionary.ContainsKey(ind) ? str + list[joinDictionary[ind]] : str).
    Where((str, ind) => !joinDictionary.ContainsValue(ind)).
    ToList();
```

It's a one-liner, but I'm not sure if that's more readable than your solution.

If you don't want to switch to zero based dictionary, you'll have to play with the indices in the LINQ expression.

Comment: it may be *shorter* but I'm not sure it's more *readable* (not criticism, more an observation based on what OP might be looking for). IMO always go for readability